# Is it possible to compute counter value inside a matrix?

Tags: arrays, loops, math, language-agnostic, counter

So normally I would do it like this:

```
counter = 1;
for(i = 0, i < 5, i++){
  for(j = 0, j < 5, j++){
    print counter
    counter++
  }
}
```

But i was wondering, can I avoid using the counter variable, and somehow compute the value using i and j ? Is there some formula for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just have to multiply i by the max value of j

```
int maxi=5;
int maxj=5;
  for(i = 0, i < maxi, i++){
    for(j = 0, j < maxj, j++){
    print i*maxj+j  
    // this starts at 0, simply add +1 if you want to start at 1
    }
  }
```

( I used maxi and maxj to avoid confusion between the two 5 )

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can try like this :

```
max = 5;
for(i = 0, i < 5, i++){
  for(j = 0, j < max, j++){
    print (i*max)+(j+1);
  }
}
```